# SQL query with associated column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

`Team`

```
id | abbreviated_name 
----------------------
1  | ATL
2  | BOS
3  | BRK
```

`Schedule` has two foreign keys `home_team_id` and `visitor_team_id`

```
id | game_date  | game_time | home_team_id | visitor_team_id
------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2021-01-01 | 7:00p ET  | 1            | 2
2  | 2021-01-02 | 6:00p ET  | 2            | 3
3  | 2021-01-03 | 7:00p ET  | 1            | 3
```

How do I query for all the rows in `Schedule` given a team abbreviated name? Say I want to find all the rows where `ATL` is playing both home and away games. I tried the following but the resulting dataset is way off.

```
SELECT *
FROM schedule s
JOIN team t
WHERE s.home_team_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM team
    WHERE team.abbreviated_name = 'ATL'
)
OR s.visitor_team_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM team
    WHERE team.abbreviated_name = 'ATL'
)
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery is correct, but when same abbreviated name has more than one id's it returns more than one row, which will give error. Example:

```
id | abbreviated_name 
----------------------
1  | ATL
4  | ATL
```

`in` satisfies this case.
Also `join` is not needed when using sub query, which will create extra records when join `on` conditions don't match

```
SELECT *
FROM schedule s
WHERE s.home_team_id in (
    SELECT id
    FROM team
    WHERE team.abbreviated_name = 'ATL'
)
OR s.visitor_team_id in (
    SELECT id
    FROM team
    WHERE team.abbreviated_name = 'ATL'
)
```

This is `join` version

```
SELECT *
FROM schedule s
LEFT JOIN team home_t on s.home_team_id=home_t.id
LEFT JOIN team visitor_t on s.visitor_team_id=visitor_t.id
WHERE home_t.abbreviated_name = 'ATL'
OR visitor_t.abbreviated_name = 'ATL'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as shown below:

```
    SELECT 
    s.id,
    s.game_date,
    s.game_time,
    s.home_team_id,
    homeTeam.abbreviated_name,
    s.visitor_team_id,
    visitorTeam.abbreviated_name
    
    FROM schedule s
    left join team homeTeam on homeTeam.id=s.home_team_id
    left join team visitorTeam on visitorTeam.id=s.visitor_team_id      
   -- where homeTeam.abbreviated_name ='ATL' OR visitorTeam.abbreviated_name='ATL'
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM schedule s
JOIN team t ON t.id IN (s.home_team_id, s.visitor_team_id)
WHERE t.abbreviated_name = 'ATL'
```

If you need abbreviated names for both commands then use, for example

```sql
SELECT s.*, t1.abbreviated_name, t2.abbreviated_name
FROM schedule s
JOIN team t1 ON t1.id = s.home_team_id
JOIN team t2 ON t2.id = s.visitor_team_id
WHERE 'ATL' IN (t1.abbreviated_name, t2.abbreviated_name)
```

Comment: it's not correct for this situation, because it'll return duplicated record, while we are going to show `home-team-name` and `visitor-team-name` beside each record from the `schedule` table

Comment: @hesamakbari The query must return duplicates. OP's query returns duplicates too - look carefully, he uses `SELECT * FROM schedule s JOIN team t`, i.e. he receives all **games**. The task is formulated as *query for all the rows in Schedule* - so team duplicates **must** exist in the output. Do not try to solve your task, solve OP's task.

Comment: the query written in the question was wrong, please mention the detail of the question

Comment: @hesamakbari I read the task in the question: *How do I query for all the rows in Schedule given a team abbreviated name?* What details do you mean? Please citate... PS. If you mean that OP needs abbreviations of both commands instead of codes, then he should say this explicitly. But he didn't say... PPS. Updated.

Comment: Just compare your answer with the corrected answer or @hesamakbari

Comment: @hesamakbari Please distinguish between the correct answer and the answer that satisfied the author (accepted). Yes, perhaps the author did not ask what he wanted to ask. And, perhaps, the answer that solves the problem somehow is enough for him.